# AmStockCharts Axis Orientation to Right Side of the Chart

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I have an AmStock chart as follows http://jsfiddle.net/w6p1kqrm/embedded/result/
Now I want to change the value Axis from `left` to `right`. Are there any ways to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you edit your question to include (some part of) your code and add some information about which things you've tried to do yet? This will add some context to your question and keep it meaningful when when the link you've provided dies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to achieve [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w6p1kqrm/1/embedded/result/) ?
Just add following few lines of code to your config `JSON` object

```
valueAxesSettings: {
    id: "g1",
    position: "right",
    dashLength: 0
}
```